# Error: Program "make" not found in PATH

Tags: eclipse, path, fortran

I'm starting coding in Fortran 90 with Eclipse neon to prepare myself for my internship and I have a problem when I try to build a program.

```
Error: Program "make" not found in PATH PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\mingw\bin;c:\mingw32\msys\1.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Ingrid\Desktop\M2\MODF\g95\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin;C:\Users\Ingrid\Desktop;]
```

Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: Have you uninstall JRE(Java Runtime Environment) as error showing the same thing. If not then install JRE then try to run your application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that's an eclipse or Java-issue. Sounds like you need to install [`make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) and add the directory with the make-executable to your `PATH`-environment variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i did it it but now I have another problem:

Comment: gfortran.exe: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found

Comment: lto (link time optimization) isn't supported for all gfortran targets, so you may simply delete that option.

Comment: How do i delete the option lto?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install TDM
2. Eclipse->project->properties->C/C++ Build->Tool chain editor->current toolchain.this item, choose "MinGW GCC"

I hope this helps!